# procedural Texture antialiasing issue in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, antialiasing, texture2d

My problem is that I have to create a procedural texture. In unity I am limited on a 4096x4096 resolution(because Of unity3d). But the problem is, that I am seeing some pixels on the texture when I use the Bresenham to draw lines. Can I use a shader to solve this problem, sorry I don`t have any experience with this. I hope you can help me.

Edit:
 [Here a picture of my current street system where you can see the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAEsp.png)

I can give you some code, but I think that would not help. I use the Texture2D object and I use the setPixel() function to draw the texture.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need more specifics in order to get an answer to a question like this.  You can post some screenshots of what you're getting vs what you'd like to be seeing and you should also be including relevant code; otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question.